# Parse textfile to extract only needed information

Tags: parsing, text

I have a file which contains tons of lines of the following format,

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFakeSink:fakesink0: last-message = "chain   ******* (fakesink0:sink) (184320 bytes, timestamp: 0:00:00.266666666, duration: 0:00:00.066666667,     offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 0 ) 0xb5d1e878"
```

Of the contents in this line, I am interested only in timestamp. i.e I only need 00.266666666. And I daily require many other sort of things like this. What would be the best way to do this. Which scripting language can handle such things easily and efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty well any scripting language with regular expression capabilities can perform tasks like this; that would include `awk`, `python`, `perl` (all of which are normally found in Linux installs) and a host of others. Learning to use regular expressions is worthwhile, but be aware that every language has its own regular expression library, with subtle differences.

But many such problems can be solved easily with normal `bash` tools like `grep` (which is also based on regular expressions). For this particular question, you could use the following:

```
grep -oE 'timestamp:[^,]*' | grep -oE '[0-9]*$'
```

(This assumes that you only want the seconds from the timestamp; you might actually want to check that the timestamp starts with `0:00:` by adding that to the first regular expression.

**grep options:**

```
-E    Use "extended" regular expressions.
-o    Only print the part of the line which matches
```

**regular expressions:**

```
[^,]*   Match any number of characters other than `,`
[0-9]*$ Match any number of digits (characters from `0` to `9`)
        at the end of the line (`$`)
```

**Another way of doing this:**

```
grep -oE 'timestamp:[^,]*' | cut -d: -f4
```

The second part selects the fourth `:`-separated field from each line.

Comment: Thanks rici, neatly explained...

Answer (score 0):

I like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this kind of task. It accepts a regular expression as field separator, so it gives you much power to split the line in the fields you want.

In this case, it could work something like a colon and a comma, and then count from the beginning:

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{ print $9 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
00.266666666
```

Answer (score -1):

Unix Bash shell scripting is the best choice for such tasks.
You can easily learn using google on how to do parsing using it.